# How to deploy multiple version of an application in production for microservice based application

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, microservices, production-environment

Is it possible to have multiple versions of service(s) deployed in production at the same time. From my assumption, this should be pretty common pattern for microservice/api based projects or mobile projects. I want to know how do you do it and what are common pattern in industry for this kind of problems. It would be helpful if your answers around AWS environment or Kubernetes environment.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With AWS API Gateway you could deploy multiple versions of your code and switch between them from the mapping templates, as explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-mapping-templates-to-handle-changes-in-your-back-end-apis/). You might also want to look into [stage variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stage-variables.html).

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to have multiple versions of service(s) deployed in production at the same time

Yes, it is possible. The idea is to keep all *used* microservices in production (v1, v2 ...) at the same time and to bring down the versions that are not used anymore. For this, you *should* somehow know when a version is not used anymore.

AFAIK, you have to options:

1. For every new version you make a new endpoint (like /v2/someApiCall) that is connected to the same (now upgraded) microservice and gradually instruct clients to use the new endpoind; when the old endpoint is not used anymore you deleted it; this is the preferred way.
2. For every new version you make a new microservice that share the same persistence with the old microservice; you should avoid the use of this solution; Netflix uses this strategy in *rare* occasions when the cost of changing old consumers is too high.

You can read more at page 62 from [Building microservices by Sam Newman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491950358).

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "new microservice that share the same persistence with the old microservice"...

Comment: A new v2 microservice that runs as a separate process and that has the new v2 source code but uses the same database instance as the old one. This is not recommended because database sharing between microservices is not recommended in general. However, if the old microservice  (v1) is to be replaced rapidly then this may be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are exposing services over An HTTP REST API, the general standard is to always base line your service urls with a version.

Eg,

```
/v1/account/getUserInfo
```

If you need to release a new version, expose it over:

```
/v2/account/getUserInfo
```

Where v2 can run over a different branch of the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

I have blogged about this: [Multi-version Service Discovery using Spring Cloud Netflix Eureka and Ribbon](http://tech.asimio.net/2017/03/06/Multi-version-Service-Discovery-using-Spring-Cloud-Netflix-Eureka-and-Ribbon.html), focussed on `Spring Cloud Netflix` components / libraries though.

But the idea is to deploy a new version of the artifact / binary in a new host / VPS / Container and have the service register with a registry server (Eureka, Consul, ....) and include metadata about the API versions it supports (v1, v2, ...). Client apps would discover which host / container / ... serves the API version needed.